# wordpress add_image_size hard crop not working

Tags: wordpress

I am using

```
add_image_size( 'featured', 1100, 333, array('center','bottom') );
```

to crop the images inside my themes functions.php.

This code crops the image properly on my local server. But, this does not crop exactly the same way on testing server. I have gd library installed and I am using php version 5.9 and Apache server.

I also tried using this http://bradt.ca/blog/image-crop-position-in-wordpress/
But it does not worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually installing "php-gd2" on my server resolved the issue.
Initially it was running "php-gd" library.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Thumbnails are only generated once (upon upload). So, any already-uploaded images will not be impacted by adding new add_image_size() calls.

You will need to regenerate your Thumbnails, e.g. using the [Regenerate Thumbnails Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/).

Comment: I have added Regenerate Thumbnails Plugin . Still its not working